# nullifying codeigniter objects or php in general?

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory-management, memory-leaks, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter and PHP to build a web app and there are lot of objects that I have to define/use inside models due to large number of queries that I have to execute.
Sometime I have to use same object multiple times inside a loop, for example:

```
  $dbData = $this->mydb->query($dbQuery);
  if($dbData->num_rows() >0 ){ //check if rows were returned
     $dbResult = $dbData->result();
     foreach( $dbResult as $index => $row){
        $dbArray[$row->JOB_NAME_STG] = $row->REC_LOADED;
    }
```

In general programming practice you should nullify the objects once they are no longer required but I haven't been able to find any detail on the best way to ensure that all the objects are nullified avoiding memory leaks for codeigniter or php in general.

Is assigning NULL to an object at the end of the function sufficient?

```
$dbData = $this->mydb->query($dbQuery);
$dbData = NULL;
```

Or codeigniter has more efficient way of ensuring that there are no memory leaks.

Should object be nullified inside a loop before using to ensure there is no memory leak?

Any pointers in the direction will be appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Comment: "In general programming practice you should nullify the objects once they are no longer required" --- who told you so? That's not true.

Comment: I never nullified any object. I don't think we should do it

Comment: I think you shouldn't nullify the pointers to objects... you should unset them. If you nullify pointers, then the pointer now points to the value NULL and loses its reference to the original memory... Thus forcing Garbage collection to sort it out!

At the very least, you could do: `unset( $dbData ); $dbData = NULL;` in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `null` makes no sense in:

1. php >= 5.3
2. applications, that don't work for hours

Do you match both items above?

Comment: I am on php version 5.3.10 and my scripts run for mins 10-20 mins.. not hours though

Comment: @user1017268: so - it makes no sense

Comment: can you tell me some details on why is NULL not required in php >= 5.3??

Comment: @user1017268: in php 5.3 new smart garbage collector was introduced

Answer (score 0):

unset() is supposed to free the variable or object from memory. However, PHP doesn't have very good garbage collection. They are trying to improve it with their new circular garbage collection with 5.3 but it still has challenges.